# Spellchecking in a dart program

Tags: dart

Is there a Dart library that provides access to dictionaries / spellcheckers? General googling around and searching through the PUB has not yielded an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any Dart libraries to do this. You can use [js-interop](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js) with a javascript library such as [bjspell](https://code.google.com/p/bjspell/).

Another option would be to make a [HttpRequest](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/HttpRequest.html) to a spell checking service, I think [google translate](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/faq) has an api for this.